# How to set random variables with a range in batch

Tags: variables, random, batch-file, range

I am making a text-based RPG game in batch, and I've been having a problem on an event in which certain weapons are supposed to do a random amount of damage between 0 and 10. Here is my code:

set /a damage=%random%/3277
echo %damage%
pause

As you can see, 3277 is approximately 32767/10. However, I keep getting 9 as the result. Can anyone help me identify what I am doing wrong? Also, is there another way I can write the code so that it has a minimum as well as a maximum? I would prefer it to be between 6 and 10, not 0 and 10.

Comment: Actually, disregard this post, I figured it out. Here is a random number with a minimum of 6 and a maximum of 10:

Comment: set /a damage=%random%*4/32767+6                                      set /a (variable)=%random%*(range=min-max)/32767+(min)

Answer (score 1):

Use modulus:

```
SET /A damage=%random% %% 11
```

This way you guarantee numbers between [0, 11[.

For such a small divisor, you will get close to a uniform distribution (assuming %random% as also a uniform distribution).